# Calculate relative frequency on one variable

Tags: r, dplyr

```
    structure(list(Effective_Date = structure(c(17257, 17563, 17652, 
17257, 17257, 17532, 17713, 17348, 17683, 17563, 17775, 17501, 
17713, 17683, 17622, 17226, 17744, 17318, 17410, 17471, 17622, 
17652, 17652, 17775, 17348, 17287, 17563, 17167, 17198, 17744, 
17440, 17257, 17379, 17591, 17501, 17622, 17532, 17652, 17501, 
17167, 17287, 17683, 17318, 17622, 17744, 17287, 17622, 17652, 
17713, 17167, 17622, 17532, 17652, 17652, 17775, 17198, 17622, 
17198, 17652, 17318, 17563, 17287, 17226, 17563, 17318, 17257, 
17379, 17379, 17563, 17591, 17563, 17440, 17501, 17471, 17287, 
17287, 17652, 17622, 17713, 17318, 17226, 17226, 17410, 17563, 
17501, 17348, 17257, 17471, 17379, 17652, 17775, 17226, 17563, 
17410, 17410, 17683, 17287, 17348, 17652, 17257), class = "Date"), 
    Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
    "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
    "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male"), Location = c("US", "US", 
    "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "India", 
    "India", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "India", 
    "India", "US", "US", "US", "India", "US", "US", "US", "US", 
    "India", "US", "India", "India", "US", "US", "US", "India", 
    "US", "India", "US", "US", "India", "US", "India", "US", 
    "India", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "India", 
    "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "India", "US", 
    "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "India", "India", "US", "US", 
    "India", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", 
    "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "India", "US", 
    "US", "US", "US", "India", "US", "US", "India", "US", "US", 
    "India")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 100 x 3
   Effective_Date Gender Location
   <date>         <chr>  <chr>   
 1 2018-09-01     Male   India   
 2 2018-05-01     Male   India   
 3 2018-03-01     Male   US      
 4 2018-03-01     Male   US      
 5 2017-06-01     Female US      
 6 2018-09-01     Male   US      
 7 2017-03-01     Female India   
 8 2017-11-01     Male   US      
 9 2017-10-01     Female US      
10 2018-09-01     Female US
```

I'm trying to calculate the % of a population that is female by both Date and Country. So the output should say something like "for 9/1/2018, there were 45% females in US and 47% in India"

When I run the following code:

```
female = tbl %>% filter(Gender %in% c("Male",'Female')) %>% 
  group_by(Effective_Date,Gender,Location) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),freq=n/sum(n)) %>% filter(Gender == "Female")
```

My frequencies all come back as 1. I feel like I'm missing something very basic. How do I group again by date and location to calculate the frequency?

Note: the filter() is in there to avoid any "not declared"'s

Comment: Try to use `freq=n/sum(n)` within a `mutate` after the `summarise`...

Comment: Yup that did it.. I also added in another group_by(Date,Location) prior to the mutate, then an ungroup, then a filter to show only Females. thanks!